# how to keep both browser zoom and hammer js swipe events in angular7

Tags: angular, hammer.js

In my application Iadded hammer.js swipeleft and swiperight events to the image tag.It works fine but It disables the browser scroll.After spending lot of time I found that the culprit is hammerjs.Becuase it disables all other browser events on that element.I found a solution from this [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-hammerjs-touch-gesture-in-angular-2) to cutomize hammerjs by setting 'touch-action' property to 'auto'.But after setting 'auto' property to touch-action then the swiper events are not working on the image.Can anyone know how can I enable both browser default zoom and hammerjs swipe events in angular7?

Comment: Hi, Pranab, did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the lightweight swipe and reorder library you can use this instead.

https://kornel.ski/slip/